# How do I extract information from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to extract the latitude and longitude from the dictionary and store it as a variable. I am using the gmaps api to geocode the street address. I also get 3 different values for the latitude and longitude, if you know why there are three that would be helpful aswell.

```
>>> geocode_result = gmaps.geocode('1280 Main St W, Hamilton, ON')
>>> print(geocode_result)
{'address_components': [{'long_name': '1280',
                          'short_name': '1280',
                          'types': ['street_number']},
                         {'long_name': 'Main Street West',
                          'short_name': 'Main St W',
                          'types': ['route']},
                         {'long_name': 'Cootes Paradise A',
                          'short_name': 'Cootes Paradise A',
                          'types': ['neighborhood', 'political']},
                         {'long_name': 'Hamilton',
                          'short_name': 'Hamilton',
                          'types': ['locality', 'political']},
                         {'long_name': 'Hamilton Division',
                          'short_name': 'Hamilton Division',
                          'types': ['administrative_area_level_2',
                                    'political']},
                         {'long_name': 'Ontario',
                          'short_name': 'ON',
                          'types': ['administrative_area_level_1',
                                    'political']},
                         {'long_name': 'Canada',
                          'short_name': 'CA',
                          'types': ['country', 'political']},
                         {'long_name': 'L8S 4L8',
                          'short_name': 'L8S 4L8',
                          'types': ['postal_code']}],
  'formatted_address': '1280 Main St W, Hamilton, ON L8S 4L8, Canada',
  'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 43.2622445, 'lng': -79.9202861},
               'location_type': 'ROOFTOP',
               'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 43.2635934802915,
                                          'lng': -79.91893711970849},
                            'southwest': {'lat': 43.26089551970851,
                                          'lng': -79.92163508029151}}},
  'place_id': 'ChIJnQcWjrKELIgR_dppfQg8IB8',
  'plus_code': {'compound_code': '736H+VV Hamilton, Ontario, Canada',
                'global_code': '87M2736H+VV'},
  'types': ['street_address']}]
```

Comment: How are you trying to extract the latitude and longitude, and what results are you getting?

Comment: Isn't this just simply `geocode_result['geomtery']['location]['lat'/'lng']`?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the latitude & longitude by simply accessing the result dictionary:

```
location = geocode_result['geometry']['location']

latitude = location['lat']
longitude = location['lng']
```

---

*Note*: Receiving "three different values for lat/lng" is slightly related to geography and [the compass itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_direction#Intercardinal_directions).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But this didn't exactly work because there are dictionaries within the dictionary. However, I was able to solve my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google Map's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro):

> geometry contains the following information:
>
> location contains the geocoded latitude, longitude value. For normal
> address lookups, this field is typically the most important.
>
> Generally the viewport is used to frame a result when
> displaying it to a user.

To extract the longitude and latitude from the dictionary:

```
longitude = geocode_result['geomtery']['location']['lng']
latitude = geocode_result['geomtery']['location']['lat']
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But this didn't exactly work because there are dictionaries within the dictionary. However, I was able to solve my problem. Thank you.